# Why isn't the html appending to the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append to a screen div the inner HTML of the span in Jquery. I tried both append and appendTo. Here's the code:

html code:

```
<div class="screen"></div>
<div class="keys">
            <!-- operators and other keys -->
            <span>7</span>
            <span>8</span>
            <span>9</span>
            <span>+</span>
            <span>4</span>
            <span>5</span>
            <span>6</span>
            <span>-</span>
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
            <span>/</span>
            <span>0</span>
            <span>.</span>
            <span>=</span>
            <span>x</span>
        </div>
```

JS code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(".keys span").click(function() {
        $(this).html().appendTo(".screen"); // also tried text() instead of html() with no luck
    });
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

`appendTo` is from one element to another, to append the content, you should use:

```
$('.screen').append($(this).html());
```

or

```
$(this).appendTo(".screen");
```

Doc:

http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: Thank you! highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to append the entire span to the .screen div you would need to clone the object the appendTo(".screen")

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(".keys span").click(function() {
        $(this).clone().appendTo(".screen");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9caqh1e/

If you are just trying to append the value inside the span. You would need to target the .screen div and append $(this).text()

```
jQuery(function() {
    $(".keys span").click(function() {
        $(".screen").append($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10L625v7/